Where clasue Fetch operation failed error
I want to write a where clause, where i want to have list of inventory items, consumed by me for the last week. I am using the following query:
(status != 'OBSOLETE') 
AND itemnum IN (SELECT itemnum FROM matusetrans WHERE issuetype = 'ISSUE'AND actualdate > SYSDATE - 7AND entered by = 'ABCDE') 
AND siteid IN (SELECT defsite FROM maxuser WHERE userid = 'ABCDE')

I am getting following error:
error message
I am sure the error is cause by entered by field, can anyone help me with that?

You're missing some spaces before ANDs: 'ISSUE'AND, 7AND. Could that be it? Also, should there be a space in entered by? I'm not familiar with Maximo, so I'll assume it makes sense to only put in the WHERE clause, as you've done.
